# Reformat data from 2 arrays and include a count

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 arrays one called question and another called answer. I would like to consider the element in question as a top category. and `answer` as the sub category. so each question can have different answers. The arrays match up. I need to reformat the data as shown below.

```
var question = 
    [ 'Prompteness',
      'Prompteness',
      'Prompteness',
      'Knowledgeable',
      'Knowledgeable',
      'Knowledgeable',
      'Knowledgeable']
  var answer =
    [ 'On hold too many times',
      'On hold too many times',
      "Lots of silence",
      'Still a little confused',
      'Still a little confused',
      'Still a little confused',
      "They knew nothing" ]
```

Example output:

```
{
    name : "Prompteness",
    value : [{
        name : 'On hold too many times',
        data : 2
    },{
        name : "Lots of silence",
        data : 1
    }]
},{
    name : 'Knowledgeable',
    value : [{
        name : 'Still a little confused',
        data : 3
    },
        name : "They knew nothing",
        data : 1
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it by yourself? Please post your code in question if you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var question = [
  'Prompteness',
  'Prompteness',
  'Prompteness',
  'Knowledgeable',
  'Knowledgeable',
  'Knowledgeable',
  'Knowledgeable'
]
var answer = [
  'On hold too many times',
  'On hold too many times',
  "Lots of silence",
  'Still a little confused',
  'Still a little confused',
  'Still a little confused',
  "They knew nothing"
]

var result = [];
question.forEach((q, i) => { // for each item in question (and answer)
  var o = result.find(e => e.name == q); // look for the question inside result
  
  if(!o) { // if it does not exist, add it
    o = {name: q, value: []};
    result.push(o);
  }
  
  var found = o.value.find(e => e.name == answer[i]); // look for the answer in the value array of this question
  if(found) // if we found the answer 
    found.data++; // increment its data property
  else // if not
    o.value.push({name: answer[i], data: 1}); // add it to the value array of this question with a count of 1
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you make the data more like Nina Scholz answer. It is more of the result I want.

Comment: The result I want is an array of objects. You have `{
    "Prompteness": {
      "name": "Prompteness",`  I don't have that.

Comment: @jackblank Updated!

Answer (score 0):

The exact structure you want in your code is somewhat weird, I'm giving you the bare basic code you need to zip and aggregate the answers, afterwards if you really want you can modify the output to match your needs.

```js
var question =
    [ 'Prompteness',
      'Prompteness',
      'Prompteness',
      'Knowledgeable',
      'Knowledgeable',
      'Knowledgeable',
      'Knowledgeable']

var answer =
  [ 'On hold too many times',
    'On hold too many times',
    "Lots of silence",
    'Still a little confused',
    'Still a little confused',
    'Still a little confused',
    "They knew nothing" ]

var result = {}

for(var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
  var q = question[i];
  var a = answer[i];

  if(!result[q]) {
    result[q] = {};
  }

  if(!result[q][a]) {
    result[q][a] = 1
  } else {
    result[q][a] = result[q][a] + 1
  }

}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested hash table approach for referencing the inner items of the result array.

```js
var question = ['Prompteness', 'Prompteness', 'Prompteness', 'Knowledgeable', 'Knowledgeable', 'Knowledgeable', 'Knowledgeable'],
    answer = ['On hold too many times', 'On hold too many times', "Lots of silence", 'Still a little confused', 'Still a little confused', 'Still a little confused', "They knew nothing"],
    result = [];

question.forEach(function (o) {
    return function (a, i) {
        var r = o;
        if (!r[a]) {
            r[a] = { _: [] };
            r._.push({ name: a, value: r[a]._ });
        }
        r = r[a];
        if (!r[answer[i]]) {
            r[answer[i]] = { name: answer[i], data: 0 };
            r._.push(r[answer[i]]);
        }
        r[answer[i]].data++;
    };
}({ _: result }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The data is what I want but this is a little too complicated for me. Are you self invoking a `forEach` with an object `{ _: result }` . I thought the first parameter of the for each would be the first element of the question array. And I don't know what a "nested hash table approach" iscan you show a simpler example of that with JavaScript. maybe something I could read online. I think a hash table means an object literal in JavaScript

Comment: `function (o) { ... }({ _: result })` is a closure over the hash table with a reference to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gcoxuf6c/5/)

i have a fanny time with this, thanks

```
var question = 
    [ 'Prompteness',
      'Prompteness',
      'Prompteness',
      'Knowledgeable',
      'Knowledgeable',
      'Knowledgeable',
      'Knowledgeable']
  var answer =
    [ 'On hold too many times',
      'On hold too many times',
      "Lots of silence",
      'Still a little confused',
      'Still a little confused',
      'Still a little confused',
      "They knew nothing" ]
      var str =question[0];
      var str1 = '';
      var p = {
            name: str,
            value: []
          }

      var _generate = [p];
      var g = 0;
      var g1 = 0;
      for(var i =0; i<question.length;i++){

        if(str!=question[i]) {
        console.log('\t',str,' -- ');
          str=question[i];
          _generate.push({
            name: str,
            value: []
          });
            g1=0;
          g++;
        }
        if(str1!=answer[i]){
        str1=answer[i];
        console.log('\t\t',answer[i],' -- ',answer.indexOf(answer[i]));


          var obj = {
            name:str1,
            data:0
          }
          str1=answer[i];
          g1++;
            _generate[g].value.push(obj)
        }
        console.log(g, g1);
        _generate[(g)].value[(g1-1)].data++;

      }

      console.log(_generate)
```